# i could not get the data in my showdata div

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, crud

I want the list all the details from tow tables using single id without refreshing the Page using Ajax

**This is my button and div:-**

```
<button id="brand" data-b_id="21">brand</button>
        <div id="#showdata"></div>##
```

**This is my javascript:-**

```
    $('#brand').click(function() {
        show_product();

        function show_product() {
            var b_id = $('#brand').data('b_id');
            //alert(bid);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php/Airtel/get_bdid')?>',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    b_id: b_id
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < data; i++) {
                        html += '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].b_name + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].d_name + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].d_id + '</td>';
                    };
                    $('#showdata').html(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**This is my controller:-**

```
 public function get_bdid(){
    $b_id=$this->input->post('b_id');
    $data=$this->mymod->get_bdid($b_id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**This is my model:-**

```
 public function get_bdid($b_id){
    $this->db->where('b_id',$b_id);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('brand');
    $this->db->join('dth', 'dth.b_name = brand.b_name'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Comment: always check your network tab from browser using ctrl+shift+i and then go to network tab. this will show url for sending ajax request and also conslog.log(response) inside success of ajax

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, there are many errors in browser developer mode.

---

1. plz Check your javascript

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

2. "get_bdid" controller is retrun "json" data type

```
success: function(data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(obj);

    // or loop
}
```